# jQuery select option code efficiency

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown that I want to prepopulate with values from a separate hidden input field.

Example: a person comes to a form with a set hidden input value - if that value matches a value in the dropdown, that option is selected.

The code below works great, but I'm curious if it possible to make it shorter/more efficient? Like with variables? So I don't have to repeat for each option? That would come in handy in the case of a large dropdown like for States that has 50 options with values. I'm still learning...thanks! I hope my question is clear.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($("input[name='Job Title']").val() === "Job 1") {
        $("#job_title option[value='Job 1']").prop("selected", true);
    }
    else if ($("input[name='Job Title']").val() === "Job 2") {
        $("#job_title option[value='Job 2']").prop("selected", true);
    }
    else if ($("input[name='Job Title']").val() === "Job 3") {
        $("#job_title option[value='Job 3']").prop("selected", true);
    }
    else if ($("input[name='Job Title']").val() === "Job 4") {
        $("#job_title option[value='Job 4']").prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

**CODEPEN**: [codepen](http://codepen.io/zuhloobie/pen/jqjJaE)

**UPDATE**: When I first asked the question, "more efficient" was in regards to code length - trimming down what I had to get the same result. "More efficient" in regards to time to run code (user experience) hadn't occurred to me. While my usage of this code is for a very simple, 4 dropdown form where time isn't a consideration...on a broader scale, for example if this form were to grow to dozens or hundreds of dropdowns, time/user experience *should* be the main goal in my opinion. That's why I chose the answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#job_title option[value='" + $("input[name='Job Title']").val() + "']")
 .prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: Holy crap - that was fast. I understand what you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just set the value of the `select`. That automatically selects the option with that value.

```
$("#job_title").val($("input[name='Job Title']").val());
```

Comment: This is a much more efficient method than the chosen answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan See http://plnkr.co/edit/F8AKWzmt8XCHOqdedSF6?p=preview `option: 2.492ms` , `select: 3.331ms`

Comment: @guest271314 A difference of less than a millisecond it negligible.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, agree. Did not post approach with concept of time, but reduction in actual text written to perform task. Your approach uses less actual written text to achieve requirement. Created plnkr attempting to verify, or learn manner in which _"This is a much more efficient method"_

Comment: If you all agree that this answer satisfies the same requirement, but more efficiently...I'll switch the chosen answer to this one. Whatever is best for the community and future noobs like myself. @guest271314 came through first with a satisfactory answer so I chose it.

Comment: @chris Have you tried the linked plnkr version 1 and 2? What do you mean by "more efficiently"?

Comment: @chris I believe this is the more idiomatic way.

Comment: @Barmar Why do you believe your solution is "more idiomatic"? This solution does meet "make it shorter" requirement

Comment: @guest271314 - I'm sorry, I haven't used plnkr before so I'm not sure what I'm to do with it. I'm a "Jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none" type of guy so my knowledge of code and what tools are available is moderate. To me, when I wrote the question, "more efficiently" was in regards to code length as this is a simple form with 4 dropdowns where time isn't a necessary requirement. But I do understand your point about the time approach.

Comment: @guest271314 - ok, I figured out the plnkr, LOL. I see your code is "more efficient" in regards to time and this one is "more efficient" in regards to code length. While my definition of "more efficient" was vague (sorry), I think yours is "most efficient" on a broader scale where time may be a consideration. User experience should be more important than how long code is. To me, anyway.

Comment: @chris The term "efficient" or phrase "more efficiently" can be extremely broad. Often, without verifiable conclusion without definition of what range of the term or phrase is. At plnkr there are two version. You can open `console`, run version at link, view results; then click `Versions` and click bottom link. As indicated by Barmar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357224/jquery-select-option-code-efficiency/37357301?noredirect=1#comment62230107_37357301 the time difference is negligible. Either approach should return expected results.

Comment: @guest271314 Because the general idea of jQuery is to make use of higher level operations. If there's a single method that does precisely what you want, it's preferred over combining multiple methods. Note that this can also be done with ordinary Javascript: `document.getElementById('job_title').value = whatever;`.

Comment: @Barmar Have not done extensive testing, though at first glance setting `selected` at actual element property appears to be "faster" than setting at parent element which must then set child element to `selected`?. Each approach calls four functions `jQuery()` twice at each, `.val()`, `.prop()` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37357259/ , `.val()` twice at your solution. Not certain what you mean by "higher level operations"? Without clear definition of how to measure "efficiency", either approach could equally meet requirement

Comment: @guest271314 - see my note above, as well as my "update" to this question, in the OP. I think your answer is best. Thank you.

Comment: @guest271314 Well, it's also a simpler selector -- just an ID, rather than having to concatenate to search for the option with a specific value.

Comment: @Barmar What is the reason for simple selector with `id` and setting value on parent element taking greater duration to complete than selecting child element having a specific attribute and setting `selected` property?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't know and I don't care. If I were worried about small differences in CPU efficiency, I wouldn't be using jQuery in the first place, I'd be calling low-level Javascript functions.